# How to create custom portlet action/mode and how to call them in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, custom-action

How to create/configure/and call custom action/mode in Liferay portlet?

Answer (score 1):

here is a forum thread about the subject : 
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/9799522#_19_message_9799522